# Plotting timedata in gnuplot

Tags: linux, charts, logging, gnuplot

I have a log file (auth.log) where non-relevant lines has been removed.
I wish to aggregate lines per hour/day into the plot, meaning that each line that is within the same hour or day is aggregated into one tic in the plot.

I have been looking into functions, but I keep getting stuck.

This is what I have so far, but it will only work if I have a "variable" for each line in the log file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot                                                          

set terminal png size 1200,800                                                  
set output "graph.png"                                                          
set title "Breakin Attempts"                                                    

set key top right box                                                           
set style data lines                                                            
set border 3                                                                    
set grid                                                                        
set pointsize 3                                                                 

set xlabel "Number of breakin attempts"                                         
set xtics nomirror                                                              
set xdata time                                                                  
set timefmt "%b %d %H:%M:%S"                                                    
set format x "%m/%d"                                                            

set ylabel "Time"                                                               
set ytics nomirror                                                              

plot "pc1.log" using 1:4 title "PC1" linecolor rgb "red", \                                                  
     "pc2.log" using 1:4 title "PC2" linecolor rgb "blue", \            
     "pc3.log" using 1:4 title "PC3" linecolor rgb "green"
```

Here is an example of the data

```
Sep 18 11:26:30 root 60.191.36.196                                              
Sep 18 11:26:34 root 60.191.36.196                                              
Sep 18 11:26:37 root 60.191.36.196
Sep 18 19:21:31 root 198.56.193.74                                              
Sep 18 19:21:33 root 198.56.193.74
```

In this case the two entries at 19:21:xx will be one tic of 2 and the three at 11:26:xx will be a tic of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the count of entries per time unit (minutes in your example). I do not know, whether gnuplot can count lines in this manner. I would use `awk` (or any language convenient for you) to cumulate the data instead. Something like this would do:

> script = '{time = $3; gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]$/, "", time); date=sprintf("%s %s %s", $1, $2, time)} date==last{count++} date!=last{print date, count; count=0}'
>
> pipe(file) = sprintf("< awk '%s' %s", script, file)
>   plot pipe("pc1.log") title "PC1"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very explicit. As Hannes, I assume you want to plot the number of lines corresponding to a certain date.

Gnuplot is not well suited for this, pre-processing the file is recommended.

However, with gnuplot 3.4 or later you can program counters (as global variables), so you could have something like this:

```
currentx=1/0
currentn=0
increaseandreturn(returnvalue)=(currentn=currentn+1,returnvalue)
startnewxandreturn(x,returnvalue)=(currentx=x,currentn=0,returnvalue)
count(x)=((x==currentx)?increaseandreturn(1/0):startnewxandreturn(x,currentn))
plot "file.gdat" using ($1-1):(count($1)) with points
```

It works only for sorted files (it will add consecutive entries, not nonconsecutive ones), `currentx` has to contain the first value (or you need to insert more tests). For dates you will need to adapt the sript a little.

You can test it e.g with a file generated by gnuplot like this:

```
set table "file.gdat"
set parametric
plot [0:20] floor(exp(t/10)),t
unset table
```